# Apple TV can't login to iCloud

Tags: icloud, appletv

I have an AppleTV 3rd generation (A1469) that will not login to iCloud.  After entering the correct password I get

"Unable to sign in.  Could not communicate with server".

If I try the wrong password, it gives a different error saying wrong password.  My account has 2FA enabled.  I've read unofficial forum posts saying you need to use a "decorated password" which is your password plus the 6 digit 2FA code appended.  But in this case my iPhone does not show any notification about a login attempt.  I've already tried "Reset all settings" in the menu and it's running the latest OS 7.3.  Network test does not identify any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is what happens when you have 2FA enabled.  The solution is to get a verification code from an iOS device.  Then use this 6-digit code together with your password on the AppleTV.  So if my password is `mypassword` then I would enter like `mypassword123456`.

Settings > Apple ID > Password & Security > Get Verification Code

[image]